# MySqlContext how to write query to variable

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a `Mysqlcontext` from which im doing queries. However, i dont know how these queries work, since i normally do the standard calls e.g. "select from where".

These are slightly different, and in this case i try to fetch an id from my `db.Users`. Unfortunately, it cant write my `UserId` to a variable?

```
var id = db.Users.Where(u => u.Email == email).Select(u => u.UserId);
```

it just returns null. How is this done correctly, and where can i find more documentation on how these queries work?

This is my updated code:

```
var id = db.Users.Where(u => u.Email == email).Select(u => u.UserId);
var materializeId = id.ToList();
int UserId = materializeId[0];
```

This actually seems to be working. Im however still confused that i have to fetch my item from a list, when there is only 1 matching ID? (There will be in all cases)

Cant i somehow query just a single id and write it to an int variable?

Comment: You are confusing database queries and ORMs like NHibernate or Entity Framework. This question has nothing at all to do with ASP.NET which is a web framework. Either use ADO.NET and run string queries as you already do, or use an ORM like Entity Framework to *map* tables to objects and use LINQ for queries

Comment: Besides, that code can never return null. Your code should return *all* matching ids - your variable should be `ids` not `id`. The resulting enumerable would be *empty* if there were no matches, not null. Please post your code. `ids` would contain nulls only if there were matching rows with null `UserId` columns

Comment: Let me just update my code!

Comment: In *any* SQL query you get a set of rows. If the query returns only one row, you get a set of rows with only one row. You didn't specify that you want a *single* value. In SQL that would mean a `TOP 1` statement. In LINQ the same can be perfomed with `.First()` or `.Single()` after `Select()`. In ADO.NET you'd also need a different call to get a single value - `ExecuteScalar`

Comment: Thank you very much for bearing with me @PanagiotisKanavos. Can you post it as an answer, so i can credit you for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this:

`var userId = (from u in db.Users
               where u.Email == email
               select u.Id).FirstOrDefault();`